# Trying to build a logging mechanism in pentaho data integration

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi, data-integration

I have the data as below.

[image]

I need the output as below.

[image]

I tried to build the transformation as below.

[image]

Here if I run the transformation I am getting output as below.

[image]

Can someone suggest the components in PDI to get the proper output?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you'll need two "*Memory Group by*" steps after SV and SV2 steps, and then a Merge Join by MPN_code.

What I don't know is if you are achieving what you want. Keep in mind that in a transformation all steps are initialized at the same time, so depending on how you calculate the Starttime and Endtime, you might get the same time for all your rows, because it's calculated as the time the first row reach the stream of the step.